# make the service return large amount of data

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-services

What's the limit of data that I can return by WCF service? I tried to play around with maxReceivedMessageSize and other parameters but still dont know what exactly the limit? Even if I get rid of "size quota for incoming messages" issue I get "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

I know that "pagging" is the best solution but at the moment I want to know what's MAX of data I can send to the client without additional complexity.
Thanks!

Regards,
Leonid

Comment: What type of data is it, out of curiosity?

Comment: just strings. list of simple objects. not binary data.

Comment: unfortunately I cant break existing interface - and I think streaming will work only with WCF clients and we offer our services for "everyone"

Answer (score 1):

There are two places you have to edit: check this http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/40770.aspx

1. edit the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig to accept a large buffer.

   binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MosaicService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                               maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
2. on the server in the web.config

add a Httpbinding and name it

which setts it to 2MB and  tell the service to use this binding

```
<services>

     <service behaviorConfiguration="TekPlayground.MosaicServiceBehavior"
name="TekPlayground.MosaicService">
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServicesBinding" contract="TekPlayground.MosaicService" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of settings that influence the amount of data you can send/receive before limits are exceeded.

- The service binding's `maxReceivedMessageSize` setting;
- The service binding's `maxStringContentLength` setting;
- The service binding's `maxArrayLength` setting;
- The service behavior's `maxItemsInObjectGraph` setting.

And, if you're hosting in IIS:

- ASP.NET's `maxRequestLength`;
- IIS' `maxAllowedContentLength` (under `security/requestFiltering/requestLimits`).

Comment: just find an article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/11/14/how-to-configure-maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx

that helps me a lot. now I can upload to the client side xml over 11M